# How can I find all solutions(count) of a sudoku game within 1 sec?

Tags: algorithm

I've tried dancing links and some other search algorithms but it won't work within the given time limit of 1 second. For a sudoku game with about 1 million solutions it takes about 10 seconds to count all solutions.

Comment: Think very fast?

Comment: (language==undefined)//return true;

Comment: 1 second for 1 million results leaves you ~1000 operations per result. With lean&mean coding that should be doable, if you don't waste too much time on the non-results. ( --> pruning )

Comment: use elimination: http://sudokublog.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/elimstep1.png

Comment: Can you post an example puzzle that should be doable in 1s?

Comment: For future reference, it's hard to give any useful advice to a question that asks 'why is my code not fast enough' without sharing any of the code

Answer (score 2):

1M results sounds a bit scary, but for fast solving basically you have to use process of elimination / constraint propagation and exhaustive search on fields with the least possible values.

An excellent article from Peter Norvig: [Solving Every Sudoku Puzzle](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

Answer (score 0):

Standard solving algorithms for Sudoku (all solutions) use [backtracking](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/42521/Sudoku). Classic variant of Sudoku has only one solution (or at least should have), so there you might use human-like techniques, but this is in the case not possible. So backtracking will be probably the only way.

But you might want to use several tricks

- Prunning of the tree (extend basic prunnign strategy of backtracking algorithm with more sophisticated conditions)
- Massive parallelism (I think that that you might benefit of superlinear accelaration of the solution, because some sub-problems might be the same, hence solvable only once, or might prune some branches of other threads)
- Use symmetry and some special properties of your setting, this is probably the best strategy, if you have some implicit knowledge
- You might try some blackbox approaches - for example [constraint](http://www.jacop.eu/) ([logic](http://eclipseclp.org/)) programming, which are highly optimized in searching in massive search space...

Comment: In prunning, it costs much more time to determine whether continue searching or just backtrack